# binding does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am trying out knockout js for asp.net mvc. I have the following helloworld example:

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout

helloworld thing
@model koHelloworld.Models.HelloWorldModel
@{
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}
<p>First name: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.FirstName)</p>
<p>Last name: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.LastName)</p>
<h2>Hello, @ko.Html.Span(m => m.FullName)!</h2>

@ko.Apply(Model)
```

model

```
namespace koHelloworld.Models
{
    public class HelloWorldModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Computed]
        public string FullName
        {
            get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
        }
    }
}
```

controller

```
public class HelloWorldController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        InitializeViewBag("Hello world");
        return View(new HelloWorldModel
        {
            FirstName = "Steve",
            LastName = "Sanderson"
        });
    }
}
```

However the binding does not work? what can be wrong?

Comment: Have you included all the required JavaScript files in your view or in your _layout.chstml?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using PerpetumSoft's Knockout library. It has several limitations. The idea is nice, but the product is quite raw. For instance, you can't derive your own controller class, because BaseController is sealed. And much more and more limitations. I suggest you using plain old javascript, html and knockout library.